# linear inequality problem - somewhat confusing.

Tags: inequality

An arrow is released with an initial velocity of $25$m/s. The height of the arrow as a function of the time is given by
$h(t) = -10t^2 + 25t$. How can we find the height of the arrow after of $2$ seconds?

For which time-interval the arrow
is to height-top to $3$m  above of the ground?

Comment: What don't you get? It is never good being spoon fed answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh honey if you are given the height of the arrow as a function of $t$, all you  have to do is to plug that $2$ second into your function so h(2) = -10*4+25*2 = -40 + 50 = -10 m. There quick and simple and dandy and I know this because mamma bear do archery!

Comment: thanks! you are right. In the second question what will be the logic?

Comment: @user5632162 Oh honey you want to find $h(t) \geq 3$, so you have $-10t^2 + 25 t \geq 3$ and if you subtract 3 from both sides you will have a quadratic equation and you know how to solve a quadratic don'tcha?

Comment: the solution is 10 ≥ 3

Comment: I would appreciate it, if you kept your domestic politics out of the site. I think there's even a rule about it :-) And it applies to both sides of the aisle. Tad of levity is largely ok, which is what you may be aiming at. But, we cannot allow free advertising! Capitalism at work, you know.